# Aurelia call function from custom element

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am trying to make my first aurelia Application and I think I have hit a wall here
I have some code here
**lists.ts**

```
export class Lists {
  protected module: string = 'lists';
  private typing : boolean = false;

  ActivateTyping() {
    console.log('inside ActivateTyping');
    this.typing = true;
    console.log(this.typing);
  }

  DeactivateTyping() {
    console.log('inside DeactivateTyping');
    this.typing = false;
    console.log(this.typing);
  }
}
```

**lists.html**

```
<template>
  <top-search action.bind="ActivateTyping"></top-search>
  ${typing}
<template>
```

**top-search.html**

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hio-top-search-nav-bar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" click.delegate="action()" blur.trigger="action()" placeholder="Search your boards">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon ion-ios-search"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
```

**top-search.ts**

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@bindable('action')
export class TopSearch { }
```

in this code, when I call the function `ActivateTyping()` from the custom element, it is getting called and it is changing the `typing` value to `true` but it is not changing in the view. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Does `${typing}` display at all? Does it show as _false_ initially?

Comment: yes it does display false initially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is not set to the instance of the view-model when you use `bind`. Use `action.call` instead of `action.bind`.

**lists.html**

```
<template>
  <top-search action.call="ActivateTyping()"></top-search>
  ${typing}
<template>
```